# Can you embed DocuSign signing in your app without generating a template?

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

I have used the DocuSign API and am able to dispatch envelopes to signers without creating the template first.

The `Document` object is created and then attached to the request:

```
$document    = new Document();
$document->setDocumentId($this->contractId);
$document->setDocumentBase64($this->getContractData());
$document->setFileExtension($this->getContractFileExtension());
$document->setName($this->contract->name);

$signHere    = new SignHere();
$signHere->setAnchorString('{{SIGNATURE}}');
$signHere->setRecipientId($this->userId);
$signHere->setName('Please sign here');
$signHere->setOptional(false);
$signHere->setScaleValue(1);
$signHere->setTabLabel('signer1sig');



$tabs        = new Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs([$signHere]);

$signer      = new Signer();
$signer->setEmail($this->user->email);
$signer->setName($this->user->profile->first_name . ' ' . $this->user->profile->last_name);
$signer->setRecipientId($this->userId);
$signer->setTabs($tabs);

$recipients  = new Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners([$signer]);

$definition  = new EnvelopeDefinition();
$definition->setDocuments([$document]);
$definition->setEmailSubject('Your test contract - Signature Requested');
$definition->setStatus('sent');
$definition->setRecipients($recipients);



$options = new EnvelopesApi\CreateEnvelopeOptions();
$options->setCdseMode(null);
$options->setMergeRolesOnDraft(null);

$envelope = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $definition, $options);
```

However, we want to present the option for both email signing and embedded signing. My question is - is it possible to embed a signing instance in our app without generating the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocuSign Server Template is needed if you want to reuse same document again and again for different signers. When you want to host embedded signing the trick is to add `clientUserId` in Signer details. Setting `clientUserId` in Signer informs DocuSign that this signer will be signing the envelope as an `embedded signer`, and it has nothing to do with DS Server Templates. You can see embedded signing example [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) and recipe also available [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app). Now if you want to present options of embedded and remote signing to signers, then you need to create two signers with same name and email. If signer completes embedded signing (subscribe for this event using DS Connect), then using API go and delete the remote signers, and viceversa.

Comment: Each document will never be reused

Comment: So you will not use Server Template, instead you will pass document to API in same way as you shared in your example. Embedded Signing has nothing to do with Server Template.

Comment: From my example above, you can see that the document is being passed as a base64 string, what parameter do i pass to get the url to send them to post signing?

Comment: For embedded signing, please check the example and recipie link in my post, also check [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/). Once envelope is sent, then DocuSign does not send an email to embedded signers, instead signer needs to come to your App, and your App needs to host the signing ceremony. For calling the signing URL, you need to call createRecipientView API, by passing clientUserId, userName, email, authenticationMethod, returnUrl.